# How do align the images side by side instead of on top of each other?

Tags: html, css

I want the images to display side by side not on top of each other.

I tried adding float:left but that didn't help.

```html
<div class="body">
  <div style="
                        display:inline-block; 
                        width: 33.33%;
                        height:110px;  background: url(https://wallpaperfm.com/img/original/6/1/3/13347.jpg) no-repeat center center; 
                            -webkit-background-size: cover;
                            -moz-background-size: cover;
                            -o-background-size: cover;
                            background-size: cover;" </div>
    <div style="
                         display:inline-block; 
                        width: 33.33%;
                        height:110px;  background: url(https://wallpaperfm.com/img/original/6/1/3/13347.jpg) no-repeat center center; 
                            -webkit-background-size: cover;
                            -moz-background-size: cover;
                            -o-background-size: cover;
                            background-size: cover;" </div>
      <div style="
                         display:inline-block; 
                        width: 33.33%;
                        height:110px; vertical-align:top; background: url(https://wallpaperfm.com/img/original/6/1/3/13347.jpg) no-repeat center center; 
                            -webkit-background-size: cover;
                            -moz-background-size: cover;
                            -o-background-size: cover;
                            background-size: cover;" </div>
```

Comment: Your html is invalid. You have missed your closing divs. Please fix your question.

Comment: Thanks that was it.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @LeeTaylor, your `divs` aren't being closed and missing `>`s.

Secondly, using inline style is not the recommended way to do markup now but to use Cascading Style Sheets ([CSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets)) instead and use element classes and or id's to apply set styling.

Example with Fix using [Flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp).

```css
.flex{
 display:flex;
 justify-content:center;
}
.img-div{
    width: 33.33%;
    height:110px;  
 background: url(https://wallpaperfm.com/img/original/6/1/3/13347.jpg) no-repeat center center; 
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
 <!-- You add the Stylesheet to the html file in the head like this -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
</head>
<body>    
 <div class="flex">
  <div class="img-div"> </div>
  <div class="img-div"> </div>
  <div class="img-div"> </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[More information on CSS and its usage](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_intro.asp)

Answer (score 0):

1. Give `float: left` in style.
2. End your starting `div` tag.

**Code:**

```html
<div style="
  display:inline-block; 
  width: 33.33%;
  height:110px;  background: url(https://wallpaperfm.com/img/original/6/1/3/13347.jpg) no-repeat center center; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  float: left;"></div>
<div style="
  display:inline-block; 
  width: 33.33%;
  height:110px;  background: url(https://wallpaperfm.com/img/original/6/1/3/13347.jpg) no-repeat center center; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  float: left;"></div>
<div style="
  display:inline-block; 
  width: 33.33%;
  height:110px; vertical-align:top; background: url(https://wallpaperfm.com/img/original/6/1/3/13347.jpg) no-repeat center center; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  float: left;"></div>
```

Comment: I changed it and it still didn't move.